# add inline asm into C macro

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I'm using mingw 4.7.2.

Could someone please tell me what's wrong in this MACRO
All I want to do is a simple asm macro which add two int and puts the result into `result` variable

```
#define add(result,a,b) \
   __asm__ __volatile__( \
"           movl %1, %%eax \n" \
"           addl %2, %%eax \n" \
"           movl %%eax, %0 \n" \
"           :"=r"(result) \
            :"r"(a),"r"(b) )
```

The compiler says `error: missing terminating " character`

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess here *"           :"=r"(result) \* something is wrong with number of quotes

Comment: You should also marke `eax` in your clobber (or use the fact that %1 is already in a register, so you don't actually need to move it anywhere to add it to another register)

Comment: thanks sharptooth , i forgot to check the syntax , but really gcc inline asm is truly painful :(

Comment: Since it's tagged C++, everything is wrong with this macro, hrhrhr.

Answer (score 4):

```
#define add(result,a,b) \
__asm__ __volatile__( \
"           movl %1, %%eax \n" \
"           addl %2, %%eax \n" \
"           movl %%eax, %0 \n" \
"           :"=r"(result) \  // <---- This line starts with a " for no reason.
            :"r"(a),"r"(b) )
```

The line marked begins with a `"` which then offsets all the other strings to the end of the macro. Just get rid of this.

I.e. your last two lines are actually:

```
"           :"=r"(result) :"r"(a),"r"(b) )
<----str----->  <----str---> <----> <-----.... No end
```

When you really meant

```
            :"=r"(result) :"r"(a),"r"(b) )
             <-->          <->    <->
```

Comment: This still fails to inform the compiler that `%eax` is clobbered, nor does it prevent `%0`, `%1` or `%2` being substituted with `%eax`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a much more flexible implementation:

```
__asm__ ("addl %2, %k0" : "=r" (result) : "%0" (a), "g" (b) : "cc")
```

Furthermore, the `__volatile__` keyword is completely unnecessary in this context.

Comment: Ah, me commenting before reading the entire thread ;-) This one is much better than the original, more compact, leaving more optimization possibilities to the compiler.